# Override garbage collector for manual php session deletion

Tags: php, session, garbage-collection, session-timeout

I want to basically stop garbage collector from deleting my php sessions so that I can manually delete them myself under conditions. How would I go about stopping garbage collector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the INI set

```
session.gc_probability = 0
```

This can also be done with `ini_set()` but make sure you do it with every `session_start()` call.

Also, it's worth noting that several Linux distros have this as the default and there is a cron job cleaning up expired sessions.